# SSAS Tabular How to Change the connection of a table

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

I created a Tabular model using VS 2013 (because later versions don't support BIDS helper (which we use for creating a folder structure organizing all measures and dimensions within the model)). After working on it for a while I noticed that I was missing a table, so I went back to go get it. The only mistake which I made was that I ended up creating a new data connection in the process. Short of dropping those tables and recreating them, is there a simple way for me to change the data source of that new table so that I can delete the redundant connection to my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague shared the following link: http://jakubka.blogspot.com/2013/11/how-to-change-connection-string-for.html.

While changing the code in this way most certainly comes across as being hacky and is probably not the highly recommended way to do things; it worked! Took me less than 5 minutes to fix and it was as simple as described in the link...

Jakub K (author of the article), thanks, man!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue today. I have VS 2017 and co-worker showed me how to do this.

1. Create New Data source in the Model(.bim file)
2. Save and close .bim file
3. Right click the .bim file and view code  . This gives you an editable view.
4. Edit the connection on all the *tables* you want changed, not the original connection.
5. Save and exist .bim file
6. Open .bim file and confirm change.

Answer (score -1):

In this case I use Tabular Editor. 
There is a good article about it [Tabular Editor Tricks - Convert to Legacy](https://tabulareditor.github.io/2019/07/03/TabularEditorTricks2.html)

[image: here is a screenshort]